# how can I create authenticating web service soap in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, authentication, soap

For connecting to the soap web service, I intend to authenticate my clients but I could not find any information on it. In my opinion, the sole method based on principals can be Soapheader.
According to the explanations I read, I wrote my code as follows:

```
IService.cs
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool DoWork();
}

Service.cs
public class Service : IService
{
    public AuthHeader Authentication;


    [SoapHeader("Authentication", Required = true)]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Returns some sample data")]
    public bool DoWork()
    {
        if (Authentication.Username == "userName" &&
        Authentication.Password == "pwd")
        {
            //Do your thing
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            //if authentication fails
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that when I start the project, there is no parameter in the Header section of the method.

```
<s:envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:header>
    <action s:mustunderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService/DoWork</action>
</s:header>
<s:body>
    <dowork xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
</s:body>
</s:envelope>
```

Would you please let me know how I can get the username and password of the webservice from client?
If you’ve got any other way, please tell me.
I appreciate your cooperation an advance.

Comment: Everyone has missed that you are mixing WCF and ASMX. `[WebMethod]` is part of the old ASMX technology, which you should never use in new development.  Please search for "wcf authentication" to learn how to create a WCF service with authentication.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by including WCFExtras (https://wcfextras.codeplex.com/).

Then you can do the following:

### 1. Define AuthHeader-Class

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthHeader
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

### 2. Inside IService: Add [SoapHeaders] to your [ServiceContract] (SoapHeaders is available after including WCFExtras). Also add [SoapHeader...] to [OperationContract]

```
[ServiceContract]    
[SoapHeaders]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WCFExtras.Soap.SoapHeader("AuthHeader", typeof(AuthHeader))]
    bool DoWork();
}
```

### 3. In Service.cs use SoapHeaderHelper (part of WCFExtras):

```
public class Service : IService
{
    [WebMethod(Description = "Returns some sample data")]
    public bool DoWork()
    {
        AuthHeader authentication = SoapHeaderHelper<AuthHeader>.GetInputHeader("AuthHeader");
        if (@"userName".Equals(authentication.Username) && @"pwd".Equals(authentication.Password))
        {
            //Do your thing
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            //if authentication fails
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```